# how to rebind event after unbinding it on click

Tags: jquery, zooming, bind, lightbox, unbind

I searched the internet for a lightbox that allows me to zoom the image at the same time.
now i only found a solution for paying a lot of money. so i decided to take two plugins and use them together. so far i went into some problems....

after a couple hours i decided to build my own lightbox and use the zoom plugin. 
so far im good with it. it opens, zoom works. if i click and hold i can change zoom ratio... if i leave image and come back (mouseover/mouseout) it closes the zoom (what is actually ok) but when im over it again, it won't start zoom again.
i know its because i unbind the click but i have to do it. else it won't work on other images. and i don't know where to rebind it and how ether :)

So the main question is: **can someone explain me how to unbind and bind correct to solve my problem?**

*(if i can do something better in my question, please comment, ill update my post than)*

So i have following code

Here is a **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/uRfyG/3/)** so you can see it

---

**EDIT**: I edited my Fiddle because i added a function to tjpzoom.js

```
function TJPunbind()
{
    console.log(obj);
}
```

*the strange thing about it is... i usually wanted to check if object still exist out of the normal call of tjpzoom but when i call console.log on the obj (containing the zoomfile data) the zoom function works fine, almost like i wanted it to work. but there is no output on console.log(obj)*

---

**My jQuery**

```
/** Lightbox inkl. Zoomer **/
var overlay = "<div class='lbOverlay'></div>";
var container = "<div class='lbContainer'><img src='' border='0' /></div>";
var blindimg = "<img id='blindimg' src='' style='display:none;' />";
$('body').append(overlay, container);


$('.imgContainer img').each(function () {


    $(this).on('click', function () {
        var width = 0;
        var height = 0;
        var faktor = 0;
        var max = 600;
        $('body').append(blindimg);

        var imagename = $(this).attr('src');
        /** Show Overlay **/
        $('.lbOverlay').fadeToggle(function () {



            /** Add IMG to Blindimg **/
            $('#blindimg').attr('src', imagename).load(function () {

                /** Get IMG Sizes **/
                width = $(this).width();
                height = $(this).height();

                /** Check if img size is bigger than max allowed **/
                if (width > max || height > max) {
                    if (width > height) faktor = width / max;
                    else faktor = height / max;

                    /** set new size **/
                    width = width / faktor;
                    height = height / faktor;
                }


                /** set up scale for image container **/
                var margin = '-' + height / 2 + 'px 0 0 -' + width / 2 + 'px';
                $('.lbContainer').css({
                    'width': width,
                        'height': height,
                        'margin': margin
                });

                /** set showen image **/
                $('.lbContainer img').attr('src', imagename).css({
                    'width': width,
                        'height': height
                });
                //console.log(width + 'x' + height);

            });

            /*
            function showZoom(element,item,image){
                $(element).click(function(){
                    TJPzoom(item,image);
                });
            }
            */

            function mouseIn() {
                $('img', this).css('cursor', 'all-scroll');
            }

            function mouseOut() {
                console.log('do some else');

            }

            /** Show Container **/
            $('.lbContainer').fadeToggle().click(function () {
                TJPzoom($('img', this)[0], imagename);
                /** unbind click so zoomer won't be fired more than once **/
                $('.lbContainer').unbind('click');
            }).hover(mouseIn, mouseOut);



        }).click(function () {
            /** close lightbox **/
            $('.lbContainer').fadeToggle(); // fadeout Container
            $(this).fadeToggle(); // fadeout Overlay
            $(this).unbind();
            $('#blindimg').remove(); //remove blingimg (will be rebind on next click)
        });

    });
});
```

**My HTML**

```
<body>
    <div class='imgContainer'>
        <img src="http://miriadna.com/desctopwalls/images/max/Landscape-with-calm-river.jpg" alt="" width="" height="" border="0" />
    </div>
    <div class='imgContainer'>
        <img src="http://www.hdwallpaperstop.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/Mountain-Landscape-Desktop-Wallpaper.jpg" alt="" width="" height="" border="0" />
    </div>
    <div class='imgContainer'>
        <img src="http://www.hdwallpaperstop.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/Beautiful-Landscape-Pictures-of-nature.jpg" alt="" width="" height="" border="0" />
    </div>
</body>
```

**My CSS**

```
.imgContainer {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
.imgContainer img {
    max-width: 150px;
}
.lbOverlay {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: black;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0.7;
    display: none;
    z-index: 1000;
}
.lbContainer {
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    background: white;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    padding: 5px;
    display: none;
    z-index: 1001;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 4px 12px 3px #333;
    box-shadow: 3px 4px 12px 3px #333;
}
.lbContainer img {
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}
```